# Maven Error (maven-surefire-plugin)

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, maven-surefire-plugin

I would like to ask on how to get rid of these errors. Once I've run my Maven test without failed test. There's no error on my project. but once I tried to put a failed test case in my Project This error is showing up. Please advise. I tried to look for a solution for 2 days already :( but can't find

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project Automation.ProjectName: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\Automation.ProjectName\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

POM.XML CODE:

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.package</groupId>
   <artifactId>Automation.ProjectName</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.1</version>
</dependency>   
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Your unit tests has Errors.

Comment: Do you want to skip your tests? If it is, add parameter -DskipTests in shell, or add "<configuration><skipTests>true</skipTests></configuration>" in your pom.

Comment: Hi @Jens, So its normal to have an error like this if my Unit test has a failed test case?

Comment: @AldrinCombalicerSy Yes

Comment: @Jens Thank you so much

Comment: @AldrinCombalicerSy You are welcome